# Why does CruiseControl.NET fail to build but using msbuild.exe from the command line works?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild, .net-2.0, cruisecontrol.net

I have a CI server running CruiseControl.NET (v1.4.4.49) which is failing a build of a VS solution file. In ccnet.config, I am already using the MSBUILD tag to build the solution, but it fails because a project that most other projects depend on either isn't building in the correct order or the build is failing.

What is eluding me is that when I execute the build (using the same parameters from ccnet.config) from the command line using msbuild.exe at C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5, the project builds as intended, and I get the same result when building from the VS 2008 GUI itself. I have searched around for a while and I hear of this happening when using DEVENV to build, but most solutions tell me to use the MSBUILD tag, which I am already using. Has anybody ever run into this issue before, and if so, any direction on how to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the output from CCNET?

Comment: It was some sort of XML logger error (one of our other developers just deleted all of the CC.NET log files, so I don't remember the exact error), but I got around the problem by commenting out the project at fault. Once I find a solution I will post my findings up here for others to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have the rep to comment, so an answer will have to do. If youre having logger probs with the standard MSBuild logger, try Christian Rodemeyer’s MsBuildToCCNet logger (mentioned here: http://ilmatte.wordpress.com/2008/06/15/cruisecontrolnet-tutorial-part-2/)

I had lots of problems with the standard MSBuild logger noted in the CC.Net docs, but Christian's works great.

With the Thoughtworks site in limbo, you may have trouble finding it. If so, let me know and Ill see if I can track down my download at the office.

Comment: We actually already have that implemented from before I was employed here.

Comment: Scratch that, it was implemented on our old CI server but I never set it up on our new one. If you have the download and could send me a link to it (the download in the link you gave me is broken) I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry about the link, it was broken for me too. I was hoping it was temporary.

Comment: http://www.glacierdigital.com/rodemeyer.zip contains the 3 files im using. I couldnt find the original zip.

Comment: Thanks! (almost 3 months later, haha)